# Is it possible to assign all module imports as a return type?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I'm new to Typescript (1.8). I'm transforming a project that was written for angular 1.4 to typescript.

One of the things I did was create a D3Service that loads the d3.js library asynchronously and makes it available in a promise.

This is my tranformed code to typescript:

```
namespace D3Provider{

    export class D3Service{
        static $inject = ['$document', '$window', '$q', '$rootScope','$timeout'];

        public d3: ng.IPromise<{}>;

        constructor(
            private $document: ng.IDocumentService, 
            private $window: ng.IWindowService, 
            private $q: ng.IQService, 
            private $rootScope: ng.IScope, 
            private $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService){
                var d = $q.defer();
                this.d3=d.promise;
                function onScriptLoad() {
                // Load client in the browser
                $timeout(function(){
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        d.resolve($window['d3']);
                    });
                });
            }
            var scriptTag = $window.document.createElement('script');
            scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
            scriptTag.async = true;
            scriptTag.charset="utf-8"
            scriptTag.src = 'bower_components/d3/d3.min.js';
            scriptTag.onload = onScriptLoad;

            var s = $document[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            s.appendChild(scriptTag);
        }
    }
    angular.module('d3', [])
    .service('d3Service', D3Service);
}
```

The public d3 property holds a promise that contains the values from window.d3.

I've downloaded the typings [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/types/npm-d3/a3171387d85d30049479ca880c617e63dca23afe/index.d.ts) which is available in ../../typings/modules/d3/index.d.ts

In the code I've then tried things like:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/modules/d3/index.d.ts" />

import * as d3lib from 'd3';
...
public d3: ng.IPromise<d3lib>;
```

The compiler then complains: error TS2304: Cannot find name 'd3lib'.

Comment: why not do `ng.IPromise<d3>` without the import?

Comment: Alternatively, have you tried [this file?](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/d3/d3.d.ts)

Comment: Hi @Paarth, Maybe I'm doiing something wrong but when I just use the reference, without the imports and say ng.IPromise<d3>, then I get an error "Cannot find name 'd3'". When I use the other file I get the same error.

Comment: I should have clarified. When you tried that, did you remove the `import *` line but leave in the `/// <reference path` line? That was my suggestion

Comment: Yes, that does give the same result. What I see also in the d3.d.ts file is that it indicates the line export = d3 as "duplicate identifier export ="

Comment: Does your tsconfig include the typings file already?

Comment: tsconfig.json only contains "compilerOptions". In the typings directory there is a index.d.ts file where I've changed the d3 index.d.ts to the new d3.d.ts file.

Comment: Alternatively, you could make your promise void (call it d3Ready or something like that) and when it is resolved - you can access d3 as global variable/namespace.

Comment: @Paarth I've added an exclude part to the tsconfig file.

Comment: @AlekseyL. Could you provide an example of how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could make your promise void (call it *ready* or something like that) and when it is resolved - you can access d3 as global variable/namespace.

```
public ready: ng.IPromise<void>;

...

var d = $q.defer();
this.ready = d.promise;
var scriptTag = $window.document.createElement('script');
scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
scriptTag.async = true;
scriptTag.charset="utf-8"
scriptTag.src = 'bower_components/d3/d3.min.js';
scriptTag.onload = () => d.resolve();
var s = $document[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
s.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

Then you can use it:

```
d3Service.ready.then(() => {
   //d3 can be used here 
});
```

Also, no need in `$timeout` and `$scope.$apply`